# Awesome CV customise cv entry

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cv, awesome-cv

In cv entry in Awesome CV, in the title I want to justify little bit further before it go in the next line

[image]

```
% Define an environment for cventry
\newenvironment{cventries}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \begin{center}
}{%
  \end{center}
}
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \

end{tabular*}%
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Because you gave us no MWE I can not test the following possibility for you :-(

Add the following code to your preamble (see the important code changing marked with `<======`):

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 2cm} R{2cm}} % <==========================================
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \

end{tabular*}%
}
```

and change both values `2cm` for your needs ...